KMP: An error occurred during an xcrun execution. Make sure that Xcode and its command line tools are properly installed
I recently have started learning KMP and got stuck on this error. I have created sample project from the Jetbrains KMP wizard. I opened the downloaded project in Android Studio and installed in the emulator and it runs fine.
But when I tried to open the iOS project in XCode, I got No such module 'ComposeApp' error on ContentView file. Refer to the screenshot.

After spending some time in the internet, I was suggested that I need to rebuild project in Android studio then the problem will be solved.
But, when I hit rebuild/make project in Android studio, I am getting this error:
> Task :composeApp:compileIosMainKotlinMetadata FAILED
e: Compilation failed: An error occurred during an xcrun execution. Make sure that Xcode and its command line tools are properly installed.
Failed command: /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -version
Try running this command in Terminal and fix the errors by making Xcode (and its command line tools) configuration correct.

 * Source files: MainViewController.kt, Platform.ios.kt
 * Compiler version: 2.0.0
 * Output kind: LIBRARY

e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.MissingXcodeException: An error occurred during an xcrun execution. Make sure that Xcode and its command line tools are properly installed.
Failed command: /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -version
Try running this command in Terminal and fix the errors by making Xcode (and its command line tools) configuration correct.

I found this command to run for command line tool installation xcode-select --install and when I run, and got
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed. Use "Software Update" in System Settings or the softwareupdate command line interface to install updates

I have the latest version of macOS, Android Studio and XCode.
What could be the issue? How could this be solved?
Any help would be appreciated.

"After spending some time in the internet, I was suggested that I need to rebuild project in Android studio then the problem will be solved." Definitely not the correct answer. Just in case anybody stumbles on this. I wrote a small post on setup. Mostly targeted at iOS devs, but it applies to all: https://touchlab.co/ideal-ios-kmp-setup

After spending several hours, I figured out that the JDK was not installed in my new MacBook. :)
